# How to create a OSM based map where users can draw lines along roads?

Tags: openstreetmap, polyline

i need to create a map, where users can draw lines along roads. i want to realize this with OSM, because i do not want to share userdata with google :)

i read about that my idea is not easy to handle, because i can not draw a line along a road on OSM rendered images. But i do not know what keywords i have to look for to get a solution for my problem.

My idea is, that users can rate a road i.e. for it's beautyfull countryside by clicking a start and an endpoint. and they should use waypoints for different rates on a road.

Could you help me? How can i create a map like [this](http://people.missouristate.edu/chadkillingsworth/mapsexamples/snaptoroad.htm), but with OSM?

Thank you :)

Comment: Did you already take a look at uMap?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [route planner](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) for this problem or even better use a software doing [map matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_matching)